# How to know the name of the unique key generated in mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have table named employee in which emp_id is the primary key. After creating the table, I realized that i wanted to add the emp_email column as unique. But while creating a unique key constraint for emp_email column, I created a unique key constraint for emp_name by mistake. Now, i didn't create this unique key by running an ALTER statement, but i used the menu in `phpmyadmin` and clicked on the unique key icon to create the key.

Now I want to drop the unique key constraint for the emp_name. But to drop it using alter statement, i need to know the name of the unique key that is generated. How can i know the name of the unique key that is generated for emp_name column?

Can I drop the unique key from `phpmyadmin` menu by clicking on to something ?

I am using XAMPP v3.2.2

Any help will be appreciated .

Comment: Try `SHOW CREATE TABLE yourTableName`

Comment: @Paul Spiegel ..it works..i tried SHOW CREATE TABLE employee , and i got the name of the unique key that was created .thks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While in phpmyadmin, select the table, then the structure tab. You should see the Indexes in the lower half, where you can modify/remove existing indexes.  It's best to copy your table first (from the operations tab), as a back up, THEN make your edits.

Comment: ..this works..I was able to drop the index through phpmyadmin..thks